Find bounds for substring in AXStaticText
I'm working on a co-pilot tool for macOS desktop apps using the Accessibility API. I need to be able to introspect editable text elements in other desktop apps. I have a working solution for text areas, but can't seem to find a solution for static texts. For context - many Electron based apps (eg. Slack) implement their text inputs as text areas that have static texts as child elements.
For text areas, this line of code works perfectly:
AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(element, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute as CFString, rangeValue, &boundsValue)
However, this approach gives incorrect bounds when applied to an AXStaticText element, or event an AXTextArea that has a static text child element.
What alternative approaches should I be trying?
Update: After i run the VoiceOver utility on it, this code works fine - any idea what the voice over utility might be doing to trigger this change?

Does Accessibility Inspector show any useful attributes?

No, its basically the same attributes as for AXTextArea

Electron apps need to have Accessibility turned on via kAXManualAccessibility before they'll return a useful tree. Have you done this? That's likely what VoiceOver is doing
