How to correctly get text cursor location from any application with Mac Accessibility APIs?
I'm developing a helper application that provides autocomplete features for any application by using macOS Accessibility APIs. I can get the right location from Xcode, VS Code and other applications using kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute (they automatically select the range I guess) .
However, I cannot get it from TextEdit, Slack etc.. The selection range comes with a 0 length for them.
P.S. Necessary permissions are granted for the app.
This method works if kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute is not 0 length:
func getCursorPosition() {
    let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
    var focusedElement : AnyObject?
    
    let error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &focusedElement)
    if (error != .success){
        print("Couldn't get the focused element. Probably a webkit application")
    } else {
        var selectedRangeValue : AnyObject?
        let selectedRangeError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedElement as! AXUIElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString, &selectedRangeValue)
        if (selectedRangeError == .success){
            var selectedRange : CFRange?
            AXValueGetValue(selectedRangeValue as! AXValue, AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCFRangeType)!, &selectedRange)
            var selectRect = CGRect()
            var selectBounds : AnyObject?
            let selectedBoundsError = AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(focusedElement as! AXUIElement, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute as CFString, selectedRangeValue!, &selectBounds)
            if (selectedBoundsError == .success){
                AXValueGetValue(selectBounds as! AXValue, .cgRect, &selectRect)
                    print("CursorX \(selectRect.origin.x), CursorY: \(selectRect.origin.y)")
            }
        }
    }
}

However below method doesn't give the right location, tried to follow another approach for TextEdit, Slack etc:
AXUIElement extended to access properties by extension methods in the below code (position, size and insertionPointLineNumber)
func getCursorPositionHacky(element: AXUIElement) {
    if element.position != nil {
        if element.size != nil {
            if element.insertionPointLineNumber != nil {
                
                // HACK: Calculate the cursor's approximate screen coordinates
                
                let lineHeight: CGFloat = 14.0 // This is an estimation from Inspector view
               
                var cursorX = element.position!.x + 10.0
 
              
                let cursorY = element.position!.y + (CGFloat(element.insertionPointLineNumber! - 1) * lineHeight)
                print("Cursor position is approximately at: (\(cursorX), \(cursorY))")
            }
        }
    }
}

Any help would be appreciated 

Duplicate of How to get focused element's cursor position using accessibility API in macOS?. Can you get the location of the character before or after the insertion point?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78323684/find-bounds-for-substring-in-axstatictext

@Willeke I was able to get the cursor position for TextEdit which returns selected range 0, by creating a range manually.  For Electron apps this approach did not work either ..
var previousCharRange = CFRangeMake(selectedRange.location - 1, 1)

For VSCode, when the AXRole is AXTextArea the AXPosition attribute worked well.

I will update here with my full solution for various cases when I get Slack to work.
